# SAML - Service Provider in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, saml, saml-2.0, service-provider

I am new to SAML and need some clarification. 
I do have the IDP server up and running, and i am trying to authenticate my Django application with IDP. The IDP's admin told me to sent them the metadata service provider which i am currently stuck.

I have been doing a lot of google research and there is so many Django packages doing this. So those packages just taking care of the connecting part or its a SP itself or i have to install something else ?

I have seen some SP vendor such as : Onelogin, Auth0...but i dont want to use them.

My goal is that to generate a SP metadata file and sent it to IDP people so they can import it.

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a SAML service provider (SP). There are multiple approaches for doing so. One of these options is embedding code in your application so that it acts as a SAML SP. Assuming that you implement enough of SAML SP "features", you would then be able to generate the SAML metadata from your application and use it to configure SP/IdP trust in your identity provider.

The original SAML/Django library was [djangosaml2](https://bitbucket.org/lgs/djangosaml2/src/default/) but it's no longer maintained; its [fork](https://github.com/knaperek/djangosaml2) is more or less active. djangosaml2 is based on PySaml2 which does support generation of SP metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, i have just install Shibboleth SP + Apache into a docker images. I got it installed successfully and connected to IDP. However, all of my applications in a different docker images. How can i point my application to that SP ? Or i am thinking wrong. Thanks

Comment: The IdP and SP can be in different containers, they're completely separate services. Shibboleth as a SP still requires an [integration](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/ApplicationIntegration) between that and your application. That integration makes certain assumptions about the architecture. If your app and Shibboleth SP are in the same Docker container, these assumptions _may_ work. If your app and Shibboleth SP are in different Docker containers, it's technically possible but much harder.

Comment: So if my app and Shibboleth SP in the same docker container, it means that, every new application which i developed, will include difference Shibboleth SP and generate a new metadata SP and sent it to IDP ?

Comment: for example : https://example.com/app-1, https://example.com/app-2.  app-1 and app-2 is pointing to different docker container. As i mentioned, I have successfully install a docker image including Shibboleth SP + Apache in https://example.com.

Comment: I am stuck at  pointing https://example.com/app-1 to SP or main url , or whatever its call to authenticate with IDP. Cause right now, only the https://example.com can talke to IDP. ??? its driving me nuts..

Comment: _So if my app and Shibboleth SP in the same docker container, it means that, every new application which i developed, will include difference Shibboleth SP and generate a new metadata SP and sent it to IDP_ - yes. If you have many apps, each in its own container, it wouldn't be a good architecture.

Comment: Thanks for still being actively response in my question. I think i am feeling better while talking to you. However, i thought that, each app/service should run on its own container is a good practice so it is easier to scale and manage. I agree that, installing Shibboleth SP on each container is not a good architecture. Thats what i am trying to use Shibboleth SP as a central SP and apps containers will connect to it. Its so easy to do it traditionally without container =)), I really appreciate any suggestion or may be i am thinking wrongly from the beginning.

Comment: A single instance of Shibboleth SP is the right way to go, you're on the right track

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197433/discussion-between-daniel8x-and-identigral).